# Get sum from MS access database

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

in a previous question I have managed to get a sum from a MS Access database but the numbers I am trying to add are both positive and negative.

How can I add the positive and negative numbers together.

The code below returns the sum but does not take into account negative numbers it treats them as positive, can this be rectified?

```
com = new OleDbCommand("SELECT sum([Points]) FROM FlightPoints WHERE [Person] =?", 
    Program.DB_CONNECTION);

com.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("", c.ID));

dr = com.ExecuteReader();

if (dr.Read())
{
    try
    {
        string[] subitems = new string[2]; // set number of items in the list
        subitems[0] = c.Rank.String + " " + c.FirstName + " " + c.Surname;
        subitems[1] = Convert.ToInt32(dr.GetDouble(0)).ToString();

        ListViewItem listItem = new ListViewItem(subitems);
        CadetPointlistView.Items.Add(listItem); // add all the subitems to the table
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: "The code below returns the sum but does not take into account negative numbers it treats them as positive" - that doesn't seem right at all. Please post some example data from your table and the results your query is giving you.

Comment: @Dai. I have found the error in my ways, it was not the code above it was my insert statement that was not inserting negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Two choices - if you can change the code, replace references to `SUM(VALUE)` with `SUM(ABS(VALUE))`; else, create a Query (SQL VIEW) that returns the original table except the value column, and calculate the absolute value using the [`ABS()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711743(v=vs.85).aspx) function ([SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d29d1f/2)).

Then, you can use the original code with the new query to calculate the result. The view can't be used to update the value column as it is calculated. Update the original table instead.